# Json to table in Mysql

Tags: mysql

while converting Json to table in Mysql having 50000 line item... It take long time to execute (20 mins).Below is patch of code... Please help me...

```
   Set I_InvoiceItemDetails = JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(p_data, '$.InvoiceItemDetails'));

    While (J < JSON_Length(I_InvoiceItemDetails)) DO
    SET B = JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(I_InvoiceItemDetails, CONCAT('$[', J, ']')));
    SET I_InvoiceNo = JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(B, '$.InvoiceNo'));

    Insert Into temp_InvoiceitemDetailsData (_InvoiceNo)
    Values (I_InvoiceNo)

    Select J + 1 Into J;

   End While;
```

Comment: Which MySQL version? Because MySQL 8.0 has a JSON_TABLE function. ( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html ) to convert JSON to a "selectable" SQL table.. But you can make it a insert like this.. `INSERT INTO table (<columns>) SELECT (<columns>)  FROM JSON_TABLE(...)`

Comment: I am using MySQL 5.7